# Slack Incoming webhook not sending complete data

Tags: python, webhooks, slack

I am using **incoming webhooks in SLACK** to send data using my **python** code.

```
slack_data = {
        "username": "Test",
        "icon_emoji": ":robot_face:",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "pretext": f"Test",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "title": self.__title,
                        "value": message
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

    headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json"}
    response = requests.post(SLACK_CHANNEL_URL, json=slack_data, headers=headers)
```

But when I run the code, I find if the **'value'** in **'fields'** is very long, it gets truncated in the slack channel.

for example:

> long message long messagelong message long messagelong message long
> messagelong message long messagelong message long messagelong message
> long messagelong message long messagelong message long messagelong
> message long messagelong message long messagelong message long m...

I tried to search a lot but couldn't find anything which helps in preventing the data from getting truncated.

Comment: Possibly documented here: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#truncating